# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass Rails mailer views not rendering variables from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, mailer

I have a restaurant resource which has many reservations.  I am trying to format the email that is sent after a reservation is created.

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Code in my app/views/reservation_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb

```
<p>Thanks for reserving a spot for <%= @restaurant.name %>!</p>
```

The reservation_mailer.rb in the mailers folder:

```
class ReservationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'johnzw89@gmail.com'

  def registration_confirmation(restaurant, reservation)
    mail(:to => reservation.email, :subject => "Reservation")
    @restaurant = restaurant
    @reservation = reservation
  end

end
```

I have a new reservations form in the restaurant show page.  Here is the reservations_controller:

```
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @reservation = @restaurant.reservations.new(params[:reservation])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        ReservationMailer.registration_confirmation(@restaurant ,@reservation).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant, status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am not sure why @restaurant is not coming up.  I suspect that the @restaurant variable from the reservations_controller is not passed to the registration_confirmation mailer method, but I am not sure... Any suggestions REALLY appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Controller action is unable to find the Restaurant with that ID. Please check in your console with the known values and then check what value you are getting in your params

Comment: `Restaurant.find(0)` would raise an error (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) before the mail is rendered/delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing order?

```
def registration_confirmation(restaurant, reservation)
  @restaurant, @reservation = restaurant, reservation
  mail(:to => reservation.email, :subject => "Reservation")
end
```